# How can i override asp.net built in ScriptResource.axd javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Here the full code : http://pastebin.com/0rSCMn3g

The function i need to override is line 1217 `_scriptIncludesLoadComplete`

This function is under `e.prototype =` line 395

So what i want is, i want to call that function with a delay. Like addin 400 ms before calling it. Is that possible? How can i do that?

I don't have access the source code since it is generated by `ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager`

Or can i modify source code some how? This is my implementation

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder" runat="Server">
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="SC1" ScriptMode="Release" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true"
    EnablePartialRendering="true" CombineScripts="true" CombineScriptsHandlerUrl="~/CombineScriptsHandler.ashx">
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

It is asp.net 4.5 c#

Answer (score 2):

`ToolkitScriptManager` is a part of open source project AJAX Control Toolkit.

You can clone its [repository](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit), rollback source code to pre v15.1 version (because `ToolkitScriptManager` was removed since v15.1) and have all the code and scripts you need locally.

Then modify it as you want and build your own version of the toolkit.